# Invalid identifier in Oracle when selecting current timestamp

Tags: oracle, timestamp, db2

The following query was working in DB2. However, when I try this in Oracle it returns an error: "invalid identifier". Here is my statement:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(20150709||' '||TIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS')  FROM DUAL
```

How can I make it work in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select to_date('08/07/2015 ' || to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss'),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

`TIME` isn't a valid built in function in oracle.  You need to either use `TO_CHAR` to pull out the time portion as a string or use some other mechanism to add in the time component.

```
SELECT TO_DATE( 20150709||' '||TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24MISS')
              , 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS')
  FROM DUAL;
```

Here's an alternate method that uses date arithmetic:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(20150709, 'YYYYMMDD')
     + (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
FROM DUAL;
```

By subtracting the truncated `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` from an untruncated timestamp you get `INTERVAL` data type that can be added or subtracted from dates and timestamps.